# Python 3 Input Dialog

Tags: user-interface, python-3.x

How do you make a simple dialog box that asks for an integer input in python 3?
The functionality should be similar to `input()` where it prompts the user, saves it to a variable, and does not continue the program until the input is received.
It can use any imports, as long as they are compatible with python 3.

Comment: 1. Pick a GUI toolkit. 2. Use it.

Comment: Well, I don't want to have to write my own class, tkinters simpledialog doesn't work in Python 3, and all the other GUI libraries I know of havent been updated to Python 3. If it was that simple, I wouldn't have asked the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written this code, I hope it does what you want, otherwise add comment the problem, and I'll try to fix it.

```
from tkinter import *
def inp():
    global inpt
    number=inpt.get()
    try:
        int(number)
        info.configure(text=number)
    except ValueError:
        info.configure(text="Please enter an integer")
    root.update()
root=Tk()
root.geometry("300x100-0+0")
Label(root,text="Input ", height=1, width=7).grid(row=0)
inpt=Entry(root, width=35)
inpt.grid(row=0, column=1)
info=Label(root,text="", height=1)
info.grid(row=3, column=1)
get=Button(root, text="Input", command=inp)
get.grid(row=2, column=1)
mainloop()
```